# Flot Chart Tooltip showing last date value of x-axis, not the current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

The values of y-axis and x-axis are fine, but when I hover at the point, it shows the last value of X, the value of Y is fine. X has date values. E.g. if I hover at `Mar/2014`, the tooltip says `Feb/2014`, or if i hover at `05/May/2014`, the tooltip says `04/May/2014`. Values on the X-axis and Y-axis are fine, only the tooltip seems to be the problem.

```
tooltipOpts: {
    content: function() {
        return "%s: %x | %y"
    },
    shifts: {
        x: -30,
        y: -50
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can manipulate %x, to increase one value or something?

Comment: Could you please adapt this jsFiddle to reproduce your problem? __http://jsfiddle.net/jamitzky/9x7aJ/__

Answer (score 2):

Question solved. I added the date format at the tooltip too, just like in xaxis.

```
tooltipOpts: {
    content: function(){
       return " %x | %y"
    },
    xDateFormat: timeFormat,
    shifts: {
       x: -30,
       y: -50
    }
 }
```

In timeFormat you put a string like `var timeFormat = "%d/%b/%Y"`.

Comment: This does not work. It just formats previous month's date.